# Работа с QGroupBox Как разместить объект этого класса в приложении и изменить его размер?

Tags: c++, qt, jqgrid

Пытаюсь разместить объект класса QGroupBox в главном окне приложения справа от текстового поля. Почему-то он отображается в левом верхнем углу и не реагирует ни на изменение размера с помощью команды resize(), ни на перемещение по сетке QGridLayout путем изменения параметров при размещении. В чем может быть проблема?

Вот реализация главного класса приложения.

```
#include "mainclass.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QTextCodec>

MainClass::MainClass(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent) 
{
    QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251"));
    QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251"));
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251"));

    QGridLayout *QMLayout = new QGridLayout;

    QTextEdit *MainTextEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    MainTextEdit->resize(600, 600);

    QGroupBox *SidePanel = new QGroupBox (this);

    QMLayout -> addWidget(MainTextEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1);

    QLabel *PLabel = new QLabel(this);

    PLabel->setText("Параметры");

    QMLayout->addWidget(PLabel, 0, 6, 1, 1);

    this->setLayout(QMLayout);
}

QGroupBox *MainClass::createFirstGroup() 
{
    QGroupBox *groupFontBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Параметры"));
    QSpinBox *FontsizeSpin = new QSpinBox (this);
    FontsizeSpin->setRange(6, 72);
    FontsizeSpin->setSuffix(" пт");

    QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout;

    QLabel *FLabel = new QLabel (this);
    FLabel->setText("Шрифт");

    vbox ->addWidget(FLabel);
    vbox ->addWidget(FontsizeSpin);

    groupFontBox->setLayout(vbox);
    groupFontBox->resize(150, 700);

    return groupFontBox;
}

MainClass::~MainClass()
{

}
```

Внутри QGroupBox не отображаются виджеты QLabel и QSpinBox, хотя я их добавил.

Вот что у меня выходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В QtCreator есть прекрасный инструмент редактирования расположения виджетов. Рекомендую им научиться пользоваться, иначе у вас будет еще очень много вопросов, а с ростом сложности приложения и проблем.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я знаю о нем. Нам запретили использовать ui-формы, чтобы мы освоили именно программирование на Qt.

Comment: И все таки, я вам рекомендую сделать все в Дизайнере, посмотреть как все это работает, поизменять настройки и так далее. Так вы поймете кухню лэйаутов, а потому уже делать все вручную

Comment: У вас GroupBox с родителем главным окном. Я вот про это: `QGroupBox *SidePanel = new QGroupBox (this);` То есть всё что вы с ним сделали - создали и сказали что он лежит напрямую в MainWindow.  При этом почему-то Label и TextEdit Вы положили на layout, а GroupBox у Вас какой-то особенный, ему не надо ?

Comment: А про `Дизайнер` Вам намекают - потому что в нём у вас справа видно дерево всех GUI элементов, с корнем главным окном. И когда вы сделаете в `Дизайнере` форму такую, какая Вам требуется, то увидите дерево всех требуемых элементов (какая Button/Label в каком layout лежит, кто у кого родитель в общем) и сможете воспроизвести это дерево программно, как Вы пытаетесь делать в Вашем примере